# How to open new window of Azure data studio from terminal

Tags: sql, editor, azure-data-studio

I'm used to the command `code .` in visual studio code to open my project directory from terminal. Is there an equivalent command in Azure data studio to do the same ?

Comment: To the bounty user ( @VSO ); this looks like a *new* question; you should be posting a new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `azuredatastudio .` for stable and `azuredatastudio-insiders .` for insider's

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\azuredatastudio.exe" on Windows

Comment: Wasn't in my path. I might have said "no" on first install, years ago.  Now I find myself using it every other day.  If like me you need to add it to PATH it is right where you'd expect to find it.